# Product Attribute text string str_replace

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute

I have a situation where I need to display a product attribute that contains text phrases separated by semicolon.  The goal is to replace the semicolon with a  I can call up the attribute using the code below however I am stuck on how to do the replacement.  I'm assuming a str_replace of some sort?

`<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('attribute_id')); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of ways of doing it. As you say str_replace should be simple enough, another alternative would be.

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape(implode('|', explode(';', $_product->getData('attribute_id')))); ?>
```